# Limit of Frechet Derivative is Derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f: \Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R^m$. Suppose that the Frechet Derivative $D_x f$ exists on some neighborhood $N_{x_0} \in \Bbb R^n$ except possibly at $x_0 \in \Bbb R^n$ itself. Further suppose that $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} D_x f = A$ for some n x m matrix A under the $L_2$ induced matrix norm. Prove/disprove that $D_{x_0}f$ is indeed defined and equals $A$.

I wasn't able to make much progress beyond the initial definitions of limit:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} D_x f = A$ means that $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0: \forall x \in B_{\delta_0}(x_0), \lVert D_x f - A \rVert_2 < \epsilon$.

The goal is to show:

$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0: \lVert f(x) - f(x_0) - A(x-x_0) \rVert < \epsilon \lVert x - x_0 \rVert$

EDIT: We may assume that $f$ is continous on $N_{x_0}$ including at $x_0$ itself.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: @eulersgroupie yes

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question.

Comment: Assuming $f$ is continuous and $n=m=1$, the result is true and follows from the property that says that $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c)$ for some $a<c<b$. Once you have proved it for $n=m=1$ the generalisation to arbitrary dimensions is straightforward.

Comment: @No-one Sorry, I'm not familiar with Lesbegue integration. How would we obtain the result in arbitrary dimensions where the Mean Value Theorem does not apply?

Comment: I've edited my answer.